# SQL Server get sales for every month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a SQL query for getting all sales for every month but if there is no sales for let's say month 3 than it should show a 0.

I currently have this SQL :

```
DECLARE @From date
DECLARE @To date
DECLARE @StyleID int
DECLARE @CustomerID int
DECLARE @ColorID int
DECLARE @ClientID int
DECLARE @DataTypeID INT

SET @ColorID = 102
SET @DataTypeID = 3

SELECT
    Months.MonthNr,
    CONCAT(Months.MonthName_EN,' ',YEAR(Orders.Created)) AS WeekBegining
    ,DataTypes.DataType 
    ,SUM(XS_1218) as XS_1218
    ,SUM(S_23) as S_23
    ,SUM(M_45) as M_45
    ,SUM(L_67) as L_67
    ,SUM(XL_811) as XL_811
    ,SUM(XXL) as XXL
    ,SUM([1Size]) as [1Size]
    ,SUM(XS_1218)+SUM(S_23)+SUM(M_45)+SUM(L_67)+SUM(XL_811)+SUM(XXL)+SUM([1Size]) as Total
FROM 
    OrdersData
LEFT JOIN 
    DataTypes ON DataTypes.ID = DataTypeID 
LEFT JOIN 
    Orders ON Orders.ID = OrdersID
LEFT JOIN 
    Months ON Months.MonthNr = MONTH(Orders.Created)
WHERE 
    (((@From is null) OR (@To is null)) OR (Orders.Created BETWEEN @From AND @To)) AND -- Period Filter
    ((@StyleID is null) OR (@StyleID = OrdersData.StyleID)) AND -- Style Filter
    ((@CustomerID is null) OR (@CustomerID = OrdersData.CustomerID)) AND -- Customer Filter
    ((@ColorID is null) OR (@ColorID = OrdersData.ColorID)) AND -- Color Filter
    ((@ClientID is null) OR (@ClientID = Orders.ClientID)) AND -- Client Filter
    ((@DataTypeID is null) OR (@DataTypeID = OrdersData.DataTypeID)) AND
    YEAR(Orders.Created) = 2013
GROUP BY 
    DataTypes.DataType, YEAR(Orders.Created), MONTH(Orders.Created), 
    Months.MonthNr, Months.MonthName_EN --DataTypes.DataType
ORDER BY 
    DataTypes.DataType, YEAR(Orders.Created), MONTH(Orders.Created),
    Months.MonthNr, Months.MonthName_EN ASC
```

and the results look like:

[image]

I need the 1,2,3 months to be all 0

Thanks To GarethD just edit your code it had a couple of bugs :)
**The sollution:**

Script:

```
DECLARE @From date
DECLARE @To date
DECLARE @StyleID int
DECLARE @CustomerID int
DECLARE @ColorID int
DECLARE @ClientID int
DECLARE @DataTypeID INT

SET @ColorID = 102
SET @DataTypeID = 3
SET @From = '2013-01-01'
SET @To = '2014-12-01'

;WITH Data AS
(   SELECT  MONTH(Orders.Created) AS MonthCreated
            ,YEAR(Orders.Created) AS YearCreated
            ,SUM(XS_1218) as XS_1218
            ,SUM(S_23) as S_23
            ,SUM(M_45) as M_45
            ,SUM(L_67) as L_67
            ,SUM(XL_811) as XL_811
            ,SUM(XXL) as XXL
            ,SUM([1Size]) as [1Size]
            ,SUM(XS_1218)+SUM(S_23)+SUM(M_45)+SUM(L_67)+SUM(XL_811)+SUM(XXL)+SUM([1Size]) AS Total
    FROM    OrdersData
            LEFT JOIN DataTypes 
                ON DataTypes.ID = DataTypeID 
            LEFT JOIN Orders 
                ON Orders.ID = OrdersID
    WHERE 
    (((@From is null) OR (@To is null)) OR (Orders.Created BETWEEN @From AND @To)) AND -- Period Filter
    ((@StyleID is null) OR (@StyleID = OrdersData.StyleID)) AND -- Style Filter
    ((@CustomerID is null) OR (@CustomerID = OrdersData.CustomerID)) AND -- Customer Filter
    ((@ColorID is null) OR (@ColorID = OrdersData.ColorID)) AND -- Color Filter
    ((@ClientID is null) OR (@ClientID = Orders.ClientID)) AND -- Client Filter
    ((@DataTypeID is null) OR (@DataTypeID = OrdersData.DataTypeID))
    GROUP BY YEAR(Orders.Created),MONTH(Orders.Created) --DataTypes.DataType
)
SELECT  m.MonthNr,
        m.MonthYear,
        WeekBegining = CONCAT(m.MonthName_EN,' ',ISNULL(YearCreated,MonthYear)),
        XS_1218 = ISNULL(d.XS_1218, 0),
        S_23 = ISNULL(d.S_23, 0),
        M_45 = ISNULL(d.M_45, 0),
        L_67 = ISNULL(d.L_67, 0),
        XL_811 = ISNULL(d.XL_811, 0),
        XXL = ISNULL(d.XXL, 0),
        [1Size] = ISNULL(d.[1Size], 0),
        Total = ISNULL(d.Total, 0)
FROM    Months AS m
        LEFT JOIN Data AS d
            ON d.MonthCreated = m.MonthNr AND d.YearCreated = m.MonthYear
WHERE m.MonthYear BETWEEN YEAR(@From) AND YEAR(@To)
ORDER BY m.MonthYear,m.MonthNr
```

Months Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Months](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MonthNr] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MonthName_EN] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [MonthYear] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Months] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

populate months table with values and it works like a charm

result: 
[image]

hope this helps someone

Comment: Please read [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) about the problems using `BETWEEN` with continuous-range types (like timestamps), especially in SQL Server.

Comment: thanks man for the good blog post, it was very informative and i made changes to my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to select from your `Months` table, and left join to the data, rather than the other way round,

```
WITH Data AS
(   SELECT  MONTH(Orders.Created) AS MonthCreated
            ,DataTypes.DataType 
            ,SUM(XS_1218) as XS_1218
            ,SUM(S_23) as S_23
            ,SUM(M_45) as M_45
            ,SUM(L_67) as L_67
            ,SUM(XL_811) as XL_811
            ,SUM(XXL) as XXL
            ,SUM([1Size]) as [1Size]
            ,SUM(XS_1218)+SUM(S_23)+SUM(M_45)+SUM(L_67)+SUM(XL_811)+SUM(XXL)+SUM([1Size]) AS Total
    FROM    OrdersData
            LEFT JOIN DataTypes 
                ON DataTypes.ID = DataTypeID 
            LEFT JOIN Orders 
                ON Orders.ID = OrdersID
    WHERE 
    (((@From is null) OR (@To is null)) OR (Orders.Created BETWEEN @From AND @To)) AND -- Period Filter
    ((@StyleID is null) OR (@StyleID = OrdersData.StyleID)) AND -- Style Filter
    ((@CustomerID is null) OR (@CustomerID = OrdersData.CustomerID)) AND -- Customer Filter
    ((@ColorID is null) OR (@ColorID = OrdersData.ColorID)) AND -- Color Filter
    ((@ClientID is null) OR (@ClientID = Orders.ClientID)) AND -- Client Filter
    ((@DataTypeID is null) OR (@DataTypeID = OrdersData.DataTypeID)) AND
    Orders.Created >= '20130101' AND
    Orders.Created < '20140101'
    GROUP BY DataTypes.DataType,MONTH(Orders.Created) --DataTypes.DataType
)
SELECT  Months.MonthNr,
        WeekBegining = CONCAT(Months.MonthName_EN,' ',YEAR(Orders.Created)),
        XS_1218 = ISNULL(d.XS_1218, 0),
        S_23 = ISNULL(d.S_23, 0),
        M_45 = ISNULL(d.M_45, 0),
        L_67 = ISNULL(d.XS_L_671218, 0),
        XL_811 = ISNULL(d.XL_811, 0),
        XXL = ISNULL(d.XXL, 0),
        [1Size] = ISNULL(d.[1Size], 0),
        Total = ISNULL(d.Total, 0)
FROM    Months AS m
        LEFT JOIN Data AS d
            ON d.CreatedMonth = m.MonthNr;
```

This way you will show the months even when there is no orders data.

Note, I have changed this line:

```
YEAR(Orders.Created) = 2013
```

To

```
Orders.Created >= '20130101' AND
Orders.Created < '20140101'
```

The latter is [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) and can take advantage of an index on the `Created` column, whereas the latter is not and can't.

Also, it depends how you actually call this query, but you may want to consider using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, this may allow for a much better execution plan, the query will compile at run time, and predicates like this:

```
(@DataTypeID is null) OR (@DataTypeID = OrdersData.DataTypeID)
```

Can be evaluated for the specific value of `@DataTypeID` you are passing. Without this you will always end up with a table scan, whereas with it you may end up with an index seek when `@DataTypeID` is not null.

Comment: i added the fixed code to the question please edit your so its the same and i will remove it from the question then, thanks you saved me allot of time :)

Comment: would be awesome if this could support multiple years also because now if i specify the year lets say from 2013-01-01 to 2014-12-30 it returns the same results as before :( i added more details to the question please take a look.

Comment: Could you not change your months table to also include year? Pre-populate it with all the years you might need, then your left join can be on month and year.

Answer (score 1):

You should start the `FROM` clause with `Months` and `LEFT JOIN` to the other tables then.
Something like the following?

```
--previous code
FROM Months
LEFT JOIN Orders ON Months.MonthNr = MONTH(Orders.Created)
LEFT JOIN DataTypes ON Orders.ID = OrdersID
LEFT JOIN OrdersData ON DataTypes.ID = DataTypeID 
--next code
```